# Extracting timestamp from timestamp with time zone Presto

Tags: sql, presto

Is there a native Presto function that provides support to extract the timestamp from a timestamp with time zone?

Taking something like this

```
SELECT 
PARSE_DATETIME('2022-03-13+02:00:99 UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm:99 ZZZ') AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS utc_time
```

Which returns a value of:

> 2022-03-13+02:00:99 UTC

To:

> 2022-03-13+02:00:99

I couldn't find information in the docs for this kind of support. It seems as though my only option is to convert this as a varchar, remove the ' UTC' characters, and then re-convert this into a timestamp if I want to remove the time zone suffix from the timestamp with time zone

Comment: "Which returns `2022-03-13+02:00:99 UTC`" - it actually returns `2022-03-13+02:00:00 UTC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just cast to timestamp:

```sql
SELECT cast(PARSE_DATETIME('2022-03-13+02:00:99 UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd+HH:mm:99 ZZZ') as timestamp) utc_time
```

Output:

| utc_time |
| --- |
| 2022-03-13 02:00:00.000 |